# Azure Pipeline of C# and .Net is creating extra folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, msbuild-task

I have a DevOps team and have very less experience with C# and .NET.
I have code written by dev team.

This is the folder structure of the project:

[image: Folder Structure of Project]

Now when I built the software using visual studio community edition. It creates this folder structure.

```
Global.asax
Web.config
app_data
bin
Properties
```

But when i am running the build via Azure Devops Pipeline, then folder structure is changed.

```
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
  displayName: Installing nuget

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: nuget restore
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'
    feedsToUse: config
    nugetConfigPath: NuGet.config

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '**\*.sln'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:OutDir=$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    createLogFile: true
    logFileVerbosity: diagnostic
  name: BulidingSolutionTask

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Build Artifacts'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

Below is folder structure.

```
_PublishedWebsites/Mainproject/Global.asax
_PublishedWebsites/Mainproject/Properties  
_PublishedWebsites/Mainproject/Web.config
_PublishedWebsites/Mainproject/bin
_PublishedWebsites/webjob1/bin/FileSandDirecotriesOfWebJob
_PublishedWebsites/webjob2/bin/FileSandDirecotriesOfWebJob
```

Why am I getting extra folder created `_PublishedWebsites/Mainproject` and why Webjob1 and 2 has bin folder inside? Is it a development problem or build problem and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Your first screenshot is the structure of the "solution" in .NET, which is where your SLN file lives.  Your second screenshot is of your "project" in .NET, which is where your CSPROJ file lives.  If you only want to build the *project* but not the *solution* you would want to specify that in your DevOps tasks as `**/XYZ.csproj` (where "XYZ" is the name of the CSPROJ file in the Mainproject folder) rather then building the entire solution, which likely houses those other projects that you're getting in your build output.

Alternatively, you could leave the SLN build, and then use the following build args:

```
msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"'
```

And then simply this for your  publish:

```
- publish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
  artifact: drop
```

This will put your individual projects into ZIP files that can then be deployed independently (i.e. if you were to want to deploy webjob1 or webjob2 later, you would have that option in your release pipeline).

Comment: Let me try something . I had a discussion with my developer and he mentioned something similar..Let me give it a shot will update you.